# Understanding Python's `property` and `__init__`

Tags: python, object, built-in

Consider the following class:

```
class HotDog():

    def __init__(self):
        self.v_th = 10

    def _new_property(obj_hierarchy, attr_name):
        def set(self, value):
            obj = reduce(getattr, [self] + obj_hierarchy.split('.'))
            setattr(obj, attr_name, value)
        def get(self):
            obj = reduce(getattr, [self] + obj_hierarchy.split('.'))
            return getattr(obj, attr_name)
        return property(fset=set, fget=get)

    x.vthresh = 77

    v_th = _new_property('x', 'vthresh')
```

If I were to create an instance of this class -- say, `x = HotDog()` -- I would find that `x.v_th == 10`.  Why is this the case?  It seems to me that the value should be set to 10 initially, but then overwritten when `self.v_th` is rededfined to be `_new_property('x', 'vthresh')`.  Is the code in `__init__` executed after this other code when `x` is initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All code at class scope is executed when the class is created. The `__init__()` method is called when the object is created. Therefore all class scope code is run before the `__init__()` method is.